# why <double> is allowed in STL

Tags: c++

I have seen that template cannot be defined with double, since it is not integral value. for example, the following code won't compile:

```
template <double x> double func()
{
    return x;
}
```

however, I wonder why in STL is it allowed do define container of double? thanks!

Comment: There’s a huge difference between `template<double x>` and `x<double>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mixing typename and type instance.
When you do:

```
template <int a> struct A {};
```

You are declaring a template struct that'll be different by a tag and this tag is an integer.
Thus, `A<1>` and `A<2>` will be completely different types.

When you do:

```
template <typename T> struct A { T a; A(T a) : a(a) {} };
```

You are declaring a template struct that'll be different by the type given. Thus, you can't write that: `A<1>` or `A<2>` since `1` or `2` is not a type but a value.

You'll write `A<int>` and any int will use that **same** type, so `A<int> a(1)` is exactly the same type as `A<int> b(2)`

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing template type parameters with template non-type parameters. In your example the parameter is a value of type `double`. In `std::vector<double>` the parameter is the type `double`.

`double` values arent really made to be compared for equality, while there is no such issue for the type `double`.

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder why in STL is it allowed do define container of double?

Because a container of double doesn't need to have a template **non-type** argument of type double. The language allows any type, incluing double to be passed into template **type** arguments, which is what a generic container would use to specify the value type.

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not allow floating point literals to to be used as template non-type parameters. Cf, integral types:

```
template <int N> class foo{};
```

is allowed but

```
template <double N> class bar{};
```

is not. The rationale behind this is that much of the implementation of floating point types is not specified by the standard. So it would be difficult to define which specialisation of `bar` would be applicable.

Comment: Within the same platform, there isn't any problem (the floating point format, while not specified in the standard, is the same for the same platform anywhere in the codebase). Since the ABI is not specified either in the standard, there is no cross platform specialization for type int. So this answer is incomplete, IMHO

Comment: I think, althrough (it's my interpretation, as it's hard to say why something is not in a standard), that since you can perform arithmetic operations on the template parameter for non-type, having float here would be a real pain to implement for compilers.